# popup does not get overlaid in the map

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to use popup of Mapbox gl js and for some reason it is not getting overlaid on top of map. Can any one please help me on it.

This is my code

```
import DeckGL from "@deck.gl/react";
import { useRef} from "react";
import { LineLayer } from "@deck.gl/layers";
import {COORDINATE_SYSTEM} from "@deck.gl/core";
import { Map, Popup } from "react-map-gl";
import { SimpleMeshLayer } from "@deck.gl/mesh-layers";
import { CubeGeometry } from "@luma.gl/core";
import {OBJLoader} from "@loaders.gl/obj"

const intitalViewState = {
  longitude: -122.4004935,
  latitude: 37.7900486,
  zoom: 15,
  bearing: 0,
};

const MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN = "MAP_KEY";


  function showPopUp(){
    return (<Popup longitude={-122.4004935} latitude={37.7900486} anchor="bottom">
        You are here
      </Popup>)
  }

function SampleDeckGL() {
  const mapComponentRef = useRef(null);

  const postLoadHandler = () => {
    let self = mapComponentRef.current;
    console.log(
      mapComponentRef.current.on("zoom", () => {
        console.log("my zoom level is", self.getZoom());
      })
    );
  };

  const myWorker = new Worker("workers/main.js");
    myWorker.postMessage(["hi", "i am pravin"]);

  myWorker.onmessage = (e) => {
  let message = e.data;
  console.log("Message received from worker", message);
};

const layer3 = new SimpleMeshLayer({
  id: 'SimpleMeshLayer',
  data: [{position: [200, 200, 0]}, {position: [500, 300, 0]}],
  
  /* props from SimpleMeshLayer class */
  
  getColor: d => [0, 255, 0],
  // getOrientation: d => [0, Math.random() * 180, 0],
  getPosition: d => d.position,
  mesh: new CubeGeometry(),
  opacity: 0.3,
  sizeScale: 100,
  getScale: (d)=>[2, 1, 1],
  loaders: [OBJLoader],
  pickable: true,
  coordinateSystem: COORDINATE_SYSTEM.METER_OFFSETS,
  coordinateOrigin: [-122.4004935, 37.7900486, 0]
});


  return (
    <DeckGL
      initialViewState={intitalViewState}
      controller={true}
      layers={[
        new LineLayer({
          id: "line-layer",
          data: [{ sourcePosition: [0, 0], targetPosition: [5, 5] }],
        }),layer3,
      ]}
    >
      <Map
        ref={mapComponentRef}
        mapboxAccessToken={MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN}
        mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
        antialias={true}
        onLoad={postLoadHandler}
      >
       {showPopUp()}
      </Map>
    </DeckGL>
  );
}

export default SampleDeckGL;
```

It is getting renderered but down the map[![enter image description here][1]][1]

You can see in the buttom there is "You are here" text and if i scroll up i see map.

I am not able to figure out what am i doing wrong
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmtLp.png